# How hide URL of links creating PDF with PhatomJS?

Tags: javascript, url, pdf, phantomjs

I'm starting to use PhantomJS to generate PDF's, but in the places where I'm adding a link PhantomJS is placing aside the complete URL between parenthesis. I wan to avoid that behaviour if can be done. Any one knows how to do it?

[image: Example of the PDF]

Answer (score 3):

After googling around I found that somebody added that behaviour using CSS, you can read it in https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10196 where the CSS added is:

```
a[href]:after {
content: "( " attr(href) " )";
text-decoration: underline;
margin-left: 2px;
color: #428bca;}
```

Then to avoid that you can include in your CSS a rule to clean up the content rule:

```
a[href]:after { content : "" }
```

And then works as should. You can also read more about it in https://github.com/alanshaw/markdown-pdf/issues/63